# Cannot import gi.repository in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm wasting lot of time trying to find out a way to import the module gi.repository in Python3, no matter what I try to install, using pip or using apt seems nothing works.
I can only find issues and answers from many years ago, even if the guide I'm following is from only a year ago.
This guide (https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/) is to create a bluetooth service on the Raspberry Pi (I',m usign the 4, 8GB).
I'm building a Flutter app to control the raspberry via BLE to manage some hardware attached via GPIO.
Even turning ON and OFF a led seems so difficult and it takes absolutely too many lines of code to accomplish. Anyone has some advice to make it simple?

- I'm using python3 virtualenv
- My statement is: from gi.repository import GLib
- The error message is: ImportError: No module named gi.repository
- Using: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- Obviously I already tried pip install and apt install to solve this

Comment: I updated the question, thank you for your support :)

Comment: I was looking for some alternative, I found the bluezero library and I think you wrote it, now I'm running the cpu_temperature.py script and I have the same error of gi.repository. I installed with pip the library at the link you suggested(option 1) but It doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I did it and now the script runs, but I can't understand why the raspberry cannot be seen by other devices (I also used bluetoothctl to turn on advertisement)

Comment: Okay, my fault, using btmon I noticed that the script works and I can connect to the RPI, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ukBaz the solution is creating a new environment with the `'--system-site-packages'` option: so the solution is:

```
python3 -m venv --system-site-packages env_name
```

...now the script runs and the `gi.repository` import works!